# How can I convert Intersystems Cache Global Objects to SQL or a more readable format?

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems

I am using Intersystems Cache 2018.1.4. The data is stored in Globals and from what I see the only way to get data out is by using the export tool used. However, the only file format that I seem to be able to export to is .gof files. Is there a way to export or manipulate the data to be in a more tabular readable format with the end goal of being able to perform data analysis in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a persistent class that describes the global.  When the class is compiled it will create a corresponding SQL table for which you can use SQL against.